# Clicking on web-table with selenium python 3

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

```
<tr id="GBPUSD" class="filled" title="Great Britain Pound vs US Dollar
Calculation: Forex
Trade: Full access" draggable="true" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><td 
id="symbol" class="symbol"><div class="container"><span class="content">
<span class="i down">&nbsp;</span>GBPUSD</span></div></td>
<td id="bid" class="down" style="text-align: right;">
<div class="container"><span class="content">1.28106</span></div></td>
<td id="ask" class="down" style="text-align: right;"><div class="container">
<span class="content">1.28116</span></div></td><td></td></tr>
```

This is the html code for the item that i want to doubleclick on with selenium webdriver.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@id='GBPUSD']")
    elem.click()
    elem.click()
```

This is my python code, but I keep getting an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: 
Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='symbol']/div] 
because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='symbol']/div]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
```

Please help me :(

Comment: Remove the `]` after the div tag.

Comment: Still unable to locate element:(

Comment: Check the xpath string . It should be have proper quotes "//*[@id='symbol']/div"

Comment: still unable to locate element

Answer (score 0):

Your code is showing one XPath, but your error message is showing another one -- the XPath in your error message is wrong (`//*[@id='symbol']/div]`) and should be changed to `//*[@id='symbol']/div`

The code in your sample is not actually the code that's throwing the error here.

Also, you can double click properly like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


// wait for element to exist
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@title, 'Great Britain Pound')]")))

// double click the element
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.double_click(elem).perform()
```

Comment: @ictloser Updated my answer to wait on the presence of the element before clicking. If you receive a TimeoutException, then the element is not displayed on the page.

Comment: This is the new error:

```in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:```
sorry im an amateur

Comment: The table does not exist on your page then. Is there an `iframe` element appearing higher up in the DOM? You posted your HTML, and my code is based off the HTML you posted, but there are many other factors on your page that I am unaware of which may be causing this error. Posting the full HTML, or a link to the page you are automating, will help.